# instruct std::list.push_back() to make use of the heap allocated memory address

Tags: c++, list, stl

As far as I know `std::list` stores it's elements internally in a doubly linked list format which means heap memory is allocated. Suppose if I already have a variable that is heap allocated using `new`, can I instruct `std ::list push_back()` function to make use of this memory in it's internal doubly linked list instead of freshly allocating new memory and then copy the data into that new memory. This is a sample code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

struct St {
    int a;
    int b;
};

int main()
{
    std::list<St> St_list;
    St *st = new St;
    st->a = 1;
    st->b = 2;

    St_list.push_back(*st); // can i instruct St_list to use the memory address of st
    
    std::cout << st << std::endl;
    std::cout << &St_list.back() << std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nope, sorry, `std::list` does not work this way. Besides each object in the list, it also has forward and reverse internal pointers that `std::list` uses internally. They are, of course, missing from the object you `new`ed.

Comment: Your best bet might be to `emplace_back` an default constructed element and directly writing to that node instead of using `st` at all.

Comment: You'd have to use a custom allocator that gives the list the desired memory to use. Not impossible; just esoteric.

Comment: So why not `std::list<St*>` (or better `std::list<std::unique_ptr<St>>`) (your code leaks memory)?

Comment: @KamilCuk If this is possible then we can avoid memory leak my setting the variable to `nullptr` after `std::list` take ownership of that memory. You know just like move assignment

Comment: This is like exactly what `std::unique_ptr` does.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest answer is NO, the memory cannot be re-used.

To explain a little - the internal node class of `std::list` does not keep the "pointer" to value - but value itself. This node is defined more or less like this:

```
template <class T>
struct List_Node {
   T value; 
   List_Node* prev;
   List_Node* next;
};
```

So there is no possibility to "re-use" allocated memory.

But - nodes can be transferred between `std::list<T>` objects with [splice](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice), thus we can avoid reallocation.

```
std::list<St> st{{1,2}};

std::list<St> St_list;
St_list.splice(St_list.end(), st);
// now st is empty, St{1,2} is in St_list - no "reallocation" happened
```